# css3 animation pause at the middle of the screen

Tags: css

Basically this is a ball.
This ball comes from left to right.
**I want that the ball pauses when it arrives in the middle of the screen, after 3 seconds it should fade out right**
How do I do that?

```
div.new-goal {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-animation: movein 1.0s ease-out 0s 1, moveout 2.1s ease-in 1s 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: $green2;
}
```

ps: It's SASS

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8B9Lx/2/ There is some flickering on the ball when reaches middle of the sccreen, I think that is due calc() result.

Comment: thank you. Thats ok for me. please make an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="ball"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#ball {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    -webkit-animation: move 8s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move
{ /* 
    8s : 100% = 3s : x 
    x = 37.5%
    */
    37.5% {
        left: calc(50% - 25px); opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        left: calc(50% - 25px); opacity: 1;
    }
    85% {
        left: 80%; opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8B9Lx/3/

Comment: Good answer ! You can avoid the calc value in the left using     margin-left: -25px;  see   http://jsfiddle.net/8B9Lx/4/

Comment: @vals Ohhh, yes! I was thinking about calc() and I completely forgot good old negative margins :D Thank you, this removed bug.